# Filter dataframe for multiple inputs in SelectizeInput Shiny

Tags: r, dataframe, reactive-programming, shiny

I have a Shiny app that shows various metrics from a dataframe called `demographicdata` based on the demography chosen by the user.

Sample data for 5 geographies-

`demographicdata`

```
    structure(list(Geography = c("AK", "AL", "AR", "AZ", "CA"), `Sum of Total Persons` = c(855385L, 
5293523L, 3766990L, 6420943L, 37431000L), `Sum of Total Families2` = c(199849L, 
1375812L, 991124L, 1551127L, 8540363L), `Sum of Total Pop Non-Hispanic White` = c(514947L, 
3513711L, 2825573L, 3712555L, 15076071L), `Sum of Total Pop Non-Hispanic Black/African American` = c(23112L, 
1430075L, 585477L, 239295L, 2165712L), `Sum of Total Pop Hispanic only` = c(44256L, 
195145L, 226525L, 1903995L, 14054449L), `Sum of Total Pop Non-Hispanic American Indian/Alaska Native` = c(164157L, 
28974L, 25122L, 259769L, 169113L), `Sum of Total Pop Non-Hispanic Asian` = c(45630L, 
54301L, 39553L, 170643L, 4777879L), `Sum of Total Pop Non-Hispanic Native Hawaiian/other Pacific Islander` = c(7749L, 
2082L, 5732L, 10969L, 128793L), `Sum of Total Female Pop2` = c(406897L, 
2722926L, 1914617L, 3230172L, 18821643L), `Sum of LMI Pop` = c(18648L, 
256265L, 95286L, 431282L, 2680252L), `Sum of MIN Pop` = c(229268L, 
1243264L, 531623L, 2059293L, 22733389L)), .Names = c("Geography", 
"Sum of Total Persons", "Sum of Total Families2", "Sum of Total Pop Non-Hispanic White", 
"Sum of Total Pop Non-Hispanic Black/African American", "Sum of Total Pop Hispanic only", 
"Sum of Total Pop Non-Hispanic American Indian/Alaska Native", 
"Sum of Total Pop Non-Hispanic Asian", "Sum of Total Pop Non-Hispanic Native Hawaiian/other Pacific Islander", 
"Sum of Total Female Pop2", "Sum of LMI Pop", "Sum of MIN Pop"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

The app works perfectly when just one demography is chosen but it crashes when I try to introduce multiple selections into the selectizeInput box.

[image]
Here's a minimal example of the entire code

app.r

```
ui <- fluidPage(

sidebarLayout(
sidebarPanel(

  selectizeInput(inputId = "demography", 'Choose MSA/MD for calculating Demographics', 
                 choices = c("Select a geography",sort((demographicdata$Geography)))
  ),

  actionButton(inputId="DatabyPage", label="Calculate")

),

mainPanel(

  tabsetPanel(

    tabPanel("Page 1 - Demographic Summary",

             fluidRow(
               column(width =12, tableOutput("Population")))
    )))
 ))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

observeEvent(input$DatabyPage, {

  Population = c("Total Population",
                 "Total Families",
                 "White",
                 "Black",
                 "Hispanic/Latino",
                 "Native American",
                 "Asian",
                 "HOPI",
                 "Total Minority",
                 "Number of Females",
                 "Population in LMI Tracts",
                 "Population in Minority Tracts"
  )

  Values = c(demographicdata$`Sum of Total Persons`[demographicdata$Geography== input$demography], 
             demographicdata$`Sum of Total Families2`[demographicdata$Geography==input$demography],
             demographicdata$`Sum of Total Pop Non-Hispanic White`[demographicdata$Geography==input$demography],
             demographicdata$`Sum of Total Pop Non-Hispanic Black/African American`[demographicdata$Geography==input$demography],
             demographicdata$`Sum of Total Pop Hispanic only`[demographicdata$Geography==input$demography],
             demographicdata$`Sum of Total Pop Non-Hispanic American Indian/Alaska Native`[demographicdata$Geography==input$demography],
             demographicdata$`Sum of Total Pop Non-Hispanic Asian`[demographicdata$Geography==input$demography],
             demographicdata$`Sum of Total Pop Non-Hispanic Native Hawaiian/other Pacific Islander`[demographicdata$Geography==input$demography],
             (demographicdata$`Sum of Total Persons`[demographicdata$Geography==input$demography]) - (demographicdata$`Sum of Total Pop Non-Hispanic White`[demographicdata$Geography==input$demography]),
             demographicdata$`Sum of Total Female Pop2`[demographicdata$Geography==input$demography], 
             demographicdata$`Sum of LMI Pop`[demographicdata$Geography==input$demography],
             demographicdata$`Sum of MIN Pop`[demographicdata$Geography==input$demography])


  Percent = c("","",
              Values[3]/Values[1],
              Values[4]/Values[1],
              Values[5]/Values[1],
              Values[6]/Values[1],
              Values[7]/Values[1],
              Values[8]/Values[1],
              Values[9]/Values[1],
              Values[10]/Values[1],
              Values[11]/Values[1],
              Values[12]/Values[1])

  Values = prettyNum(Values,big.mark=',')
  Percent[3:12] = paste(round(100*as.numeric(Percent[3:12]), 2), "%", sep="")


  Population = data.frame(Population, Values, Percent)
  colnames(Population) = c("Population Demographics", "Number", "Percent")
  rm(Values, Percent)

  output$Population <- renderTable({

    Population
  })

})

 })
# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Basically I want to access dataframes for multiple selections of demography

Example - If the user selects Alabama and Montana, I want to access the cumulative sum of `demographicdata$'Sum of Total Persons'` in Alabama and Montana.

I know I have to introduce some sort of reactive element here but I'm having a hard time trying to put it together.

Any thoughts?  Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are couple of things to change.

1) use `multiple=TRUE` in `selectizeInput`
2) Replace `==` with `%in%` for more than one element comparison

```
 ui <- fluidPage(

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(

      selectizeInput(inputId = "demography", 'Choose MSA/MD for calculating Demographics', multiple = TRUE, 
                     choices = c("Select a geography",sort((demographicdata$Geography)))
      ),

      actionButton(inputId="DatabyPage", label="Calculate")

    ),

    mainPanel(

      tabsetPanel(

        tabPanel("Page 1 - Demographic Summary",

                 fluidRow(
                   column(width =12, tableOutput("Population")))
        )))
  ))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  observeEvent(input$DatabyPage, {

    Population = c("Total Population",
                   "Total Families",
                   "White",
                   "Black",
                   "Hispanic/Latino",
                   "Native American",
                   "Asian",
                   "HOPI",
                   "Total Minority",
                   "Number of Females",
                   "Population in LMI Tracts",
                   "Population in Minority Tracts"
    )

    Values = c(sum(demographicdata$`Sum of Total Persons`[demographicdata$Geography %in% input$demography]), 
               sum(demographicdata$`Sum of Total Families2`[demographicdata$Geography %in% input$demography]),
               sum(demographicdata$`Sum of Total Pop Non-Hispanic White`[demographicdata$Geography %in% input$demography]),
               sum(demographicdata$`Sum of Total Pop Non-Hispanic Black/African American`[demographicdata$Geography %in% input$demography]),
               sum(demographicdata$`Sum of Total Pop Hispanic only`[demographicdata$Geography %in% input$demography]),
               sum(demographicdata$`Sum of Total Pop Non-Hispanic American Indian/Alaska Native`[demographicdata$Geography %in% input$demography]),
               sum(demographicdata$`Sum of Total Pop Non-Hispanic Asian`[demographicdata$Geography %in% input$demography]),
               sum(demographicdata$`Sum of Total Pop Non-Hispanic Native Hawaiian/other Pacific Islander`[demographicdata$Geography %in% input$demography]),
               (sum(demographicdata$`Sum of Total Persons`[demographicdata$Geography %in% input$demography])) - (sum(demographicdata$`Sum of Total Pop Non-Hispanic White`[demographicdata$Geography %in% input$demography])),
               sum(demographicdata$`Sum of Total Female Pop2`[demographicdata$Geography %in% input$demography]), 
               sum(demographicdata$`Sum of LMI Pop`[demographicdata$Geography %in% input$demography]),
               sum(demographicdata$`Sum of MIN Pop`[demographicdata$Geography %in% input$demography]))


    Percent = c("","",
                Values[3]/Values[1],
                Values[4]/Values[1],
                Values[5]/Values[1],
                Values[6]/Values[1],
                Values[7]/Values[1],
                Values[8]/Values[1],
                Values[9]/Values[1],
                Values[10]/Values[1],
                Values[11]/Values[1],
                Values[12]/Values[1])

    Values = prettyNum(Values,big.mark=',')
    Percent[3:12] = paste(round(100*as.numeric(Percent[3:12]), 2), "%", sep="")


    Population = data.frame(Population, Values, Percent)
    colnames(Population) = c("Population Demographics", "Number", "Percent")
    rm(Values, Percent)

    output$Population <- renderTable({

      Population
    })

  })

})
# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

-output

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this!! Anyway I can display the output as an aggregate of the selected inputs? I want the output to display the sum of total population across AL AZ in one instance instead of appearing one below the other for each input selection. For example the above output must show: Total Population = 583824

Comment: @AshwinRamesh  In that case, just do the `sum`.  Updated the post

Comment: You're a life saver thanks!! I don't know why I didn't think of that, I guess I've just been staring at this for too long.